# deserialize repeated element in xml using c#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

I get a response which contains following:

```
<carList>
<numberOfRecords>237</numberOfRecords>
<year>1982</year>
<year>1983</year>
<year>1978</year>
<year>1955</year>
<year>1998</year>
</carList>
```

this is part of bigger xml doc, I can desterilizes the rest but this part I cannot. rest of my desterilized objects comes fine.
here is my models:

```
public class Response 
{
   [XmlArray( "carList")]
   [XmlArrayItem("year")]
   //[XmlElement("carList")]
   public CarList? CarList { get; set; }
}
```

```
    public class CarList
    {
        [XmlElement("numberOfRecords")]
        public int? NumberOfRecords { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("year")]
        public List<string>? Year { get; set; }
    }
```

my deserializer:

```
XmlDeserializer xmldes = new XmlDeserializer();

var deserializedResponse = xmldes.Deserialize<Response>(response);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have a single `carList`, so this should be:

```cs
[XmlElement("carList")]
public CarList? CarList { get; set; }
```

assuming this is a child node, and not the root element (in which case: `[XmlRoot("carList")]` on `CarList` itself, and lose `Response` completely)

Comment: you're right, it's not a root element. it's part of bigger xml. my carList contains only a number of cars along with list of year. if i use the way you mentioned, 'NumberofRecords" gets populated but List of Year is empty

Comment: @Pamador works fine here: https://gist.github.com/mgravell/0a1d3a1de0cd9ab0614b375dc5425bb8 - do you have a repro that shows it not working? is the real code perhaps using xml namespaces and/or namespace prefixes?

Comment: thanks for the comment. there is name space on root element if that was you're referring to. i did similar thing but it didn't work. when i deserialise the xml, number of record gets the correct value, but my list has none.

Comment: @Pamador namespaces are critically important in xml deserialization; if you want code that matches your data, you'll need to show example xml that includes something like your scenario - otherwise *it won't work*

Comment: yes, i tried that in different project same as you did, and it works over there. here is the xml: <ABRPayloadSearchResults xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://abr.business.gov.au/ABRXMLSearch/">
<response>
<abnList>
<numberOfRecords>2680</numberOfRecords>
<abn>95437472757</abn>
<abn>38023383928</abn>
<abn>12839919648</abn>
<abn>50165055391</abn>
<abn>60306167177</abn>
</abnList>
</response>
</ABRPayloadSearchResults>

Comment: @Pamador nothing unexpected in there - I was kinda expecting the inner nodes to be in a different namespace, but: this works fine: https://gist.github.com/mgravell/c649229a7e3b2aaf906dc905c904f15b - can you show something that doesn't work?

Comment: that's strange. let me double check my code. thanks for your time

Comment: i managed to solve it. although the answer was correct but in my case it gets resolved by adding the name space to the class representing my root element in xml. also I was using Restsharp xml deserialiser. i switch to XmlSerliser and XmlTextReader to read the content. I don't know if it has something to do with this but it fixed my issue.